# Buildfire: Combine resouces from another plugin build in another stack

Tags: plugins, buildfire

Please how do I combine or make use of other plugin recourses on my plugin?
My plugins are built with HTML, CSS JS, and some on React.js. I want to make us of community wall plugin in my plugin.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways:

1. If you have access to the other plugins source code then you can always Fork/Branch the repository and enhance as needed. However, you will need to rename the plugin to something unique
2. You can create custom navigation and flow in your plugin to navigate to the other plugin. You want to use https://sdk.buildfire.com/docs/navigation/#navigateto or in your case https://sdk.buildfire.com/docs/navigation/#navigatetosocialwall to have the best user  experience you should probably consider using breadcrumbs   https://sdk.buildfire.com/docs/breadcrumbs/
3. Deep linking: if the destination plugin supports deep linking you can navigate to that plugin and pass along you additional information that opens up a deeper section of the plugin. Example in community wall you can pass it along a Wall ID and it will open up that thread for you. Deep linking can happen many ways but some are as simple as passing a query string like `?wid=XXX`